# Data such email_SignUp does not saves in my ViewModel class even though I used @Published words

Tags: swift, class, view, swiftui, observedobject

Overall, I have a ViewModel which has @Published vars

```
class Parent : ObservableObject{
    @Published var email_SignUp = ""
    @Published var password_SignUp = ""
    @Published var reEnterPassword = ""
}
```

Also, I have a View where user make interactions through textfield. Here, I used a self-made custom TextFields which take image, text and action as a parameters.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SignUpViewParent : View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Parent
    let settings = Settings()
    var body: some View{
         VStack(spacing: 20){
              CustomTextField(image: "person", placeHolder: "Email", txt: $model.email_SignUp).autocapitalization(.none)        
              CustomTextField(image: "lock", placeHolder: "Password", txt: $model.password_SignUp)
              CustomTextField(image: "lock", placeHolder: "Re-Enter", txt: $model.reEnterPassword)
              NavigationLink(destination: TestView(model: Parent())) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text("Next")
                                            .frame(width: 90,height: 50).padding(.trailing, 50)
                                            .cornerRadius(24)
                                            .foregroundColor(.init(red: 50, green: 50, blue: 50))
                                            .background(Color.init(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)))
                                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle.init())
                                            .cornerRadius(24)
                                        
                                        
                                    }.padding(.trailing)
                                    .padding(.bottom)
                                }
         }
    }
}
```

TestView is just View with other buttons not related to 'email_SignUp' and 'password_SignUp'.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @ObserverObject var model: Parent
    var body: some View {
        ...(some actions with others variables of model)
    }
}
```

Here is how my custom TextField looks like -

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomTextField : View {
    var image : String
    var placeHolder : String
    @Binding var txt : String
    var body: some View{
        
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .center)) {
            
            Image(systemName: image)
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .background(Color.white)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            
            ZStack{
                
                if placeHolder == "Password" || placeHolder == "Re-Enter"{
                    SecureField(placeHolder, text: $txt)
                
                }
                else{
                    TextField(placeHolder, text: $txt)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.leading,65)
            .frame(height: 60)
            .background(Color.white.opacity(0.2))
            .clipShape(Capsule())
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

While entering the data in textfield, - "email_SignUp" in ViewModel is not empty, however, after tapping on the NavigationLink "Next", email_SignUp in ViewModel class "Parent" becomes empty... What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You pass into navigation link destination new instance of `Parent`, but if you want use already entered values, you should pass local property, like

```
NavigationLink(destination: TestView(model: self.model)) {   // << here !!
```